# Replace parent value with its child

Tags: javascript

I have a object like this

```
{
  data: {
    name: {
      en: 'val1',
      es: 'val2'
    },
    altName: {
      en: 'val3',
      es: 'val4'
    }
  },
  otherField: {
    en: 'val5',
    es: 'val6'
  }
}
```

I need a function into which I pass a key `en` and at the output I get an object such as

```
{
  data: {
    name: 'val1',
    altName: 'val3'
  },
  otherField: 'val5'
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can recursive iterate by object fields, for example using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and check every field type/key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for your simple example this does work. This code is obviously not clean but to get the idea it demonstrates it really good i think.

```
function doCrazyStuff(objToScan, key) {
  if(objToScan instanceof Object && typeof key === "string") {
    let props = {};
    for(prop in objToScan) {
      if(typeof objToScan[prop] === "object") {
        props[prop] = doCrazyStuff(objToScan[prop], key);
      } else {
        if(prop === key) {
          return objToScan[prop];
        }
      }

    }
    return props;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

let yourObj = {
  data: {
    name: {
      en: 'val1',
      es: 'val2'
    },
    altName: {
      en: 'val3',
      es: 'val4'
    }
  },
  otherField: {
    en: 'val5',
    es: 'val6'
  }
};
console.log(doCrazyStuff(yourObj, "en"));
```

What i do here is recursion. At first i take a look at if you have given the right params to the method in this case a js-obj and a string representing the name of the property we are looking for. Then we prepare a obj we can return and loop over all properties we can find in the "objToScan" value. If a prop is also an js-obj we set the value of this prop to the result of an recursive call with the found obj and the key we are looking for. Otherwise we check if the prop we found in the obj is our key and then we return the value of it. Otherwise we do nothing.

If you need further assistance just give an answer and i will see what i can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help

```js
const data = {
  data: {
    name: {
      en: 'val1',
      es: 'val2',
    },
    altName: {
      en: 'val3',
      es: 'val4',
    },
  },
  otherField: {
    en: 'val5',
    es: 'val6',
  },
};

const replaceParent = (x, r) => {
  Object.keys(x).forEach((key) => {
    if (x[key][r]) {
      x[key] = x[key][r];
    } else if (typeof x[key] === 'object') {
      replaceParent(x[key], r);
    }
  });
};

replaceParent(data, 'en');

console.log(data);
```

**Explaination :**
What it does is it goes through the each key of given object and checks if it has key which can be used to replace. if yes then it replaces with value, otherwise only if key is object it recursively performs same operation on this object found for key leaving non object keys.

*Note: this manipulates the actual passed object because snippet works by passing references.*